# Hibernate Batch Processing: Is it good practice to insert 9000 Records in Single Batch and session?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, persistence, batch-processing

I am using Batch Processing in Hibernate.
Against 1 entity there are 9 sub entities.

I am going to fetch 12000 records using RestApi. For each record need to hit restapi again and fetch heavy payload.

**Single Transaction**:

1000 Hits to Rest API

9000 Hits to Database

Is it fine to do following for 9000 Inserts

```
public void createAll(Collection<T> ts) {
        if (ts == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (T t : ts) {
            this.em.persist(t);
        }
    }
```

after 9000 records

```
 em.flush()
```